# TextureAtlas region to Texture

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

I am trying to get a texture area from TextureAtlas, but as Texture.

I have tried:

```
textureAtlas.findRegion("explosion").getTexture();
```

but it returns the whole texture atlas image.

I need this for a class that I created similar to Sprite. I avoided using Sprite because it couldn't fit my needs.

All answers I found were for the Sprite class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably misunderstanding the concept of `Texture`, `TextureRegion` and `TextureAtlas`. There is no simple way to do what you want, nor does it make any sense to do so. Doing so would defeat the whole purpose of using a `TextureAtlas` in the first place.

You can think of a `Texture` as a one-on-one mapping with an image file on disk. A `.png` file for example. So, basically, for every image file on disk that you have, you can have a `Texture` instance. But you can't have a `Texture` instance if there isn't an image file on disk from which the texture is loaded. (strictly speaking you could create a `Texture` instance without file on disk, e.g. an in-memory file so to speak, but that's not relevant for your question)

A `TextureAtlas` is used to combine multiple smaller images into a single image file on disk. This is done using e.g. `TexturePacker`, which is a tool that uses multiple images as file on disk as input and then combines it to a single image file on disk. This is done because having one (or a few) big image is alot more performant than having many smaller images.

So, because you are using a `TextureAtlas` (which is a good thing), this means that you have only one image file on disk. And because you have only one image file on disk you also only have (and need) one `Texture` instance.

You typically should never use a `Texture` directly. Instead you should use a `TextureRegion`. This is simply a class that specifies a `Texture` along with a specific region (`x`, `y`, `width` and `height`) within that texture. Which is exactly what you are looking for. You can directly draw a `TextureRegion`, e.g. using `SpriteBatch`. So this is a very convenient way to specify an image.

Note that the `Sprite` class extends `TextureRegion` and just adds some additional convenient properties. So if you have `Sprite` then you also have a `TextureRegion`, you could simply ignore the additional properties if you don't need them.

So, if you created a class that needs an image within a `TextureAtlas` and relied on a `Texture` for that, then you implemented that incorrectly. The best you can do in that case is to modify that implementation by using `TextureRegion` instead of `Texture`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't use Sprite, because i couldn't add two different textures to it.